# Committing a change on a previous release version on master

Tags: git, bitbucket, gitkraken

Pertaining to the gitflow work flow depicted in the picture I was wondering what if someone wanted to make a revision to a version in master, but not have those changes apply to the more recent versions in master.

So for example in version 0.1 what if I had a bug that only pertained to version 0.1, I understand that I would make a hotfix branch and then push it back up to master, but wouldn't that hotfix apply to the head of master at version 1.0? How would one go about changing a specific version in master without altering the other versions in master?

[image: Gitflow]

Answer (score 1):

The green dots are `release` branches.
As detailed [in the tutorial](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/comparing-workflows/gitflow-workflow):

> you fork a `release` branch off of `develop`.
>   Creating this branch starts the next release cycle, so no new features can be added after this point—**only bug fixes, documentation generation, and other release-oriented tasks should go in this branch**.
>   Once it's ready to ship, the release branch gets merged into `master` and tagged with a version number.

The point is: even if the 0.1 release branch was already merged back to `master`, you can still add a commit on it, for old bug-fixes, and put a new tag on it (0.1.1).
You won't merge it to `master` though.